# Stripe crashes when create product in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to create a product in stripe, but when I try to make the call with stripe.products.create(), it lags, and some seconds later my server crashes due to 'JavaScript heap out of memory'.

Here is how I do it:

```
import stripePackage from 'stripe'
const stripe = stripePackage(config.stripe)

// after product is found in mongoose
stripe.products.create({
    id: product.sku,
    name: product.title,
    type: 'good',
    description: product.description,
    active: product.isAvailable,
    images: product.images,
    package_dimensions: {
        weight: product.shipping.weight * 16,
        length: product.shipping.dimension.length,
        width: product.shipping.dimension.width,
        height: product.shipping.dimension.height
    },
    shippable: true
}).then(stripeProduct => {
    console.log(stripeProduct.id);
    res.json(stripeProduct)
}).catch(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

CORS settings

```
app.use((req, res, next)=> {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, token, auth")
  res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "token")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS")
  next()
})
```

Here is the crash report from express.js:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[87147:0x102801e00]    61928 ms: Mark-sweep 1416.8 (1462.3) -> 1416.7 (1446.3) MB, 9502.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 9502 ms) last resort
[87147:0x102801e00]    72192 ms: Mark-sweep 1416.7 (1446.3) -> 1416.7 (1446.3) MB, 10263.3 / 0.0 ms  last resort


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x3ca24589cef1 <JSObject>
    1: encode(aka encode) [/Users/thousight/Projects/Project/node_modules/qs/lib/utils.js:~118] [pc=0x163bec732a95](this=0x3ca245882241 <undefined>,str=0x3ca2458822c1 <true>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1
    3: stringify(aka stringify) [/Users/thousight/Projects/Project/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:~32] [pc=0x163bec733b44](this=0x3ca245882241 <undefined>,object=0x3ca24588...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
5: v8::internal::LoadIC::LoadFullChain(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Smi>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
6: v8::internal::LoadIC::UpdateCaches(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
7: v8::internal::LoadIC::Load(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
8: v8::internal::Runtime_LoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
9: 0x163bec5840dd
10: 0x163bec732a95
```

Is there anything wrong with it? What would be the factors to cause that server crash? Thanks

Node: v8.4.0
Stripe-Node: v5.8.0

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if you `console.log` the object you're passing to `stripe.products.create()`?  Does anything look out of the ordinary?  And are you certain this is where it's crashing?

Edit: To be more specific, what does this return?

```
console.log({
  id: product.sku,
  name: product.title,
  type: 'good',
  description: product.description,
  active: product.isAvailable,
  images: product.images,
  package_dimensions: {
    weight: product.shipping.weight * 16,
    length: product.shipping.dimension.length,
    width: product.shipping.dimension.width,
    height: product.shipping.dimension.height
  },
  shippable: true
});
```

Comment: I also logged this, I am sure there is nothing wrong with this object as everything is filled out. I cannot see anything wrong though as I have been following everything written in stripe-node readme and API references. And I am certain that stripe.products.create() causes the crash since everything before it logs, and it does not trigger .then() or .catch() at all. I also tried just calling stripe.products.create() without any parameters, and it still crashes my server, which is super weird

Comment: I added my CORS settings to my question, hope that helps

Comment: How much memory does this system have?  It looks like your system is barfing when trying to stringify that object, so I think the most likely cause is something in there; what happens if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(thatobject));`?

Comment: It outputs the string perfectly

Comment: How much memory does the system have then?  Can you increase it?  What effect does that have?

Comment: 16GB, it's sealed

Comment: Ok, then there's something wrong with the object you're passing in, and it has something in it that it shouldn't have (that is much larger than what `qs` can handle converting).  I'm not really sure what more I can do/help here, without seeing the output of what's in that object.  Are you certain that's where it's failing?  And you're not getting the output of `    console.log(stripeProduct.id);` ?

Comment: Since I can log the object, I am sure it should be fine. And I am not able to get the output of console.log(stripeProduct.id)